# I want to save a .text file in a specific file directory for information entered by someone

Tags: python, pyqt5, save

Whenever this function is called all the information is saved to the list playerInfo. Now I would like to save this list as a .text file with the name being the name enter by the user (p_name) for later use in the directory:
C:\Users\Vatiekakie\OneDrive\Documents\CourseWorkProject\Players

###The code###

```
    def savePlayer(self):
        # blank list to hold player info
        playerInfo = []
        # loop through data and pull out each info
        playerInfo.append(self.p_name)
        playerInfo.append(self.p_prfname)
        playerInfo.append(self.p_dob)
        playerInfo.append(self.p_height)
        playerInfo.append(self.p_nr)
        playerInfo.append(self.p_placeob)
        playerInfo.append(self.p_weight)

        p_name = self.p_name.text()


# to save playerInfo to .text file

        playerFileName = "p_name"
        playerFile = open(playerFileName, "w")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if below mentioned code snippet works for you:

```
# to save playerInfo to .text file
playerFilePath = 'C:\\Users\\Vatiekakie\\OneDrive\\Documents\\CourseWorkProject\\Players'
playerFileName = p_name
outputPath = os.path.join(playerFilePath, playerFileName) ## import os library for this line to work
with open(outputPath, "w") as f:
    for item in playerInfo:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: Thank you @Piyush Sambhi, it creates the file, but its not saving to the Players directory I specifically created, it's saving to CourseWorkProject

Comment: @VatieKakie Check now, I have updated the solution. I missed copying outputPath in the open() method, that is why the file was getting saved in CourseWorkProject.
It will work like magic now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(playerFileName + ".txt", "a") as file:
  for item in playerInfo:
    file.write(item + "\n")
```

The file closes automatically
(This code would go instead `playerFile = open(playerFileName, "w")`